# Implementing chat in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, juggernaut, faye

I am trying to implement a `chat module` in my rails application. I looked into this railscast [Faye](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) tutorial. More through the tutorial, Ryan mentions about `broadcasting` the messages but what I want is more like `private conversations` between the clients instead of broadcasting.

Is it possible to do that through faye? or is there a better way of implementing chat in rails?

Comment: It's just a matter of changing your thinking about it. Even though it's called "broadcast", you are really just creating a unique URL for two people to subscribe to.

Answer (score 2):

There is a gem that handles the autentications for you for faye, so users can only listen on channels you subscribe them to. There is also a railscast talking about that gem.
https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub

Comment: I am trying something sort of private conversation between two people rather than a chat room. Faye's subscription is based on url, so how can that be used for private chats between individuals?

Comment: /conversation/conversation_id. How diferent a conversation is from a chat ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Faye, but assuming the principles are the same as with something like pure node.js and websockets, you'd divide the channels that can be subscribed to down into as many chats as there are occurring, then you'd require some sort of authentication before a client can subscribe to that channel, of which there are numerous approaches, as with most authentication systems (e.g. shared secret, username/password, challenge/response etc).

Answer (score 1):

I have used Ryan's tutorial on `private_pub` to achieve an a Gmail like instant messaging feature. It's actually not very complex. See how I achieved it in this tutorial http://goo.gl/l3e8zN